# Why does ServiceWorkerRegistration callback is not hitting after the successful registration of service worker?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, chrome-gcm

I am using the below script to register service worker, and would like to  Check if this service worker supports push? Just for testing purpose I am printing 'Print Service worker', but it is not getting printed to console. 
Kindly help me to trigger where I am getting wrong?

```html
function register()
{
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
    {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {scope: scope}).then(initialiseState);
    } 
    else {
        console.warn('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.');
    }
}

function initialiseState() 
{ 
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration)
        {  console.log('Print Service worker');});
}
```

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, an explanation as to why you aren't seeing the logging you expect:

Unless you call `self.clients.claim()` within your service worker, it won't take control of the current web page during the navigation when its initially registered. As for the `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` promise, it doesn't resolve until there's a service worker that controls the page. Put those two together and I would not expect your `console.log()` to execute the first time you visit the page, but I would expect it on subsequent visits (if the service worker installed properly).

There's an [example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/immediate-control/index.html) of using `self.clients.claim()` if you want to have your service worker take control of the page the very first time you navigate there.

As to your actual question, if you feel the need to feature-detect service worker push support, you should be able to just check for `'pushManager' in registration`, where `registration` is a `ServiceWorkerRegistration` object, like the one `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` resolves with. There's no need to wait until your page is controlled by a service worker. So this should work:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
    if ('pushManager' in registration) {
      // The service worker supports push
    } else {
      // The service worker doesn't support push
    }
  });
} else {
  // The browser doesn't support service workers
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for you help.

Comment: Hi Jeff,  Since it is the continuation of the question I am puting it in comment. 
When I try to access endpoint, I am getting the below error.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'endpoint' of null subscription.
The code sample with which I am trying is as follows:
        registration.pushManager.getSubscription()  
     .then(function(pushSubscription)
     {
                      
                        var  Endpoint = pushSubscription.endpoint;
                     
                                  
     });
    }
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you haven't declared a scope variable? Try:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', { scope: '/' }).then(initialiseState);
```

The other likely possibility is that you've not added a manifest file properly, instructions are here starting at 'Make a Project on the Google Developer Console': https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en